# .ajaxForm VS .ajaxForm(.....).submit()

Tags: ajaxform

I'm attempting to debug the .ajaxForm. I have the library jquery.form.js installed with jquery-1.7.1.js and jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js. When I use.ajaxForm(....).submit(), the form gets submitted, but when using .ajaxForm(.....) WITHOUT submit() the form doesn't submit. What's yet even more frustrating, is that even with .submit() in place, I can Not get execution happen inside .ajaxForm(....), regardless what I do. It appears to be I don't understand this well. I looked on line, the API description for ajaxForm and a sample are very straight forward, yet, something is wrong. Please help! Here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
            $('#lookUpFrm').ajaxForm(function(result) {                 
                    alert("AJAX:"+result)
                    success: function() {
                        $("#lookUpFrm")[0].reset();                         
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function (error, status, code){
                        $('#error_dialog').showErrorDialog();                       
                    }

                });//.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This link may help: [Trouble with ajaxForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601335/trouble-with-ajaxform)

This is a question I asked a few days ago and answered earlier today. I had quite a bit wrong with my logic (as you will see) and was trying to use the plug-in in the same way you seem to be. I posted what I had to do to get it working and it is working beautifully now. I hope this helps!